# Why the variables defined inside a for loop only exist inside of it?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

I was reading C++ Primer by Stanley B. Lippman and at the part of flow control it shows an example of a for-loop like this one:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void){
    int sum=0;
    for (int val=1; val <= 10; val++)
        sum +=val;
    std::cout << sum << std::endl; 
    return 0;

}
```

If I try `std::cout << val;` outside of the for-loop, the IDE gives me an error. But I want to understand why it happens and how it is different from this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void){
    int sum=0;
    int val;
    for ( val=1; val <= 10; val++)
        sum +=val;
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
    std::cout << val; 
    return 0;

}
```

Where I can actually print the `val` value without any problem.

Does it have something to do with local variable considering the for-loop a function that we are using inside of the main?

Comment: Because it opens a new scope, just like `{` does.

Comment: You can read more about scope [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope).

Comment: @JonathanPotter thank you for that, it will be really helpful.

Comment: Just running those two code snippets (the second needs initialisation of val) also shows clearly what's going on :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every variable has *scope*, which is (loosely speaking) its lifetime.

A variable declared in the head of a `for` loop has scope limited to the `for` loop. When control passes out of the loop, the variable passes out of scope. Exactly the same thing happens to variables declared in a function, when control passes out of the function.

Comment: Oooh this explains a lot for me, so it is just like I said, like a local variable inside of a function?

Comment: @gm_fernandes: The `for` loop is not a function, but variables declared in it have scope limited to it, yes.

Comment: @gm_fernandes Yes, that pretty much sums up the behaviour. Imagine doing like `if (something) { int x = 123; } cout << x;`, if `something` is not true `x` was never declared therefore it cannot be refered to outside that `if`.

Comment: @Beta now I understood it completely, but of course I will read more about scope, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

> Does it have something to do with local variable considering the for-loop a function that we are using inside of the main?

Nothing to do with functions; there are plenty of other ways to get a scope, including a block:

```
int main()
{
    {
       int x = 0;
    }
    std::cout << x; // error
}
```

And a for loop is another example.

Answer (score 1):

Its deliberate. Its called [scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope), Whenever you introduce a block `{ /*stuff here */ }` (and a few other places) the variables inside the block are local to the block and supersede (hide) variables of the same name defined outside the block. It helps to ensure block-local code does not tread on other variables. Can be useful when editing an old codebase and you don't want to accidentally use a wider scoped variable.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and also your explanation, it is now crystal clear for me!

Answer (score 0):

The concept behind this is called Scope of the variable. Whenever a variable is created a memory location is assigned to it. So in order to optimize the memory usage scope of the variable is defined.

In the first case, the variable is limited only to the for loop. The variable is created inside at the beginning of the loop, utilized inside the loop and destroyed when the execution comes out of the loop.

In second case, the variable is created outside the loop so it persists till the execution of the program and hence you were able to access it even after the loop.

The variable declared inside the for loop is an example of local variable and that declared outside is an example of global variables.
Not only with the loops, the local variables will also be used in if..else blocks, functions and their usage is limited only within the scope.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score -2):

Running this exact code does not turn up any errors for me. I get a value of 55 for sum and 11 for val as expected. Because you defined val outside of your for loop but in main, it should be good everywhere within the main() function to the best of my knowledge. As a general rule, if you declare a variable in between two curly braces without any fancy keywords, it should stay valid within those two curly braces (being "local" to that block of code). I am no c++ guru, so there might be exceptions to that (I am also not sure if "if" statements count as code blocks whose locally defined variables only work within the statement).

Comment: _"I would post this as a comment but I do not have enough reputations to do so"_ That's because you're supposed to watch and learn before commenting. Writing your comment instead in the wrong place is the opposite of what you're supposed to do! Never understand why people casually do the wrong thing to "workaround" clearly-explained limitations like this, especially when they know _why_ they're limited!!

Comment: That's a bit harsh.  He answered the question after all.